# how to get full momentjs api inside angular view?

Tags: angularjs, momentjs

What's the preferred method of getting a `moment()` object inside a view when using angular?

It looks like there is this project, but it does not look well maintained.

https://github.com/gdi2290/angular-momentjs

Answer (score 75, accepted):

There is a more popular angular-moment project... https://github.com/urish/angular-moment

With it, you can inject moment like this...

```
app.controller("ctrl", function($scope, moment) {
    $scope.date = new moment();
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7LHDX/)

Or if you don't need the additional functionality and directives provided by angular-moment, you can make momentjs injectable in your app by using `angular.value()` or `angular.constant()` (angular-moment uses `constant()` internally to do this)...

```
app.constant("moment", moment);

app.controller("ctrl", function($scope, moment) {
    $scope.date = new moment();
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Pe2Zc/)

Comment: Like how you can insert scripts in to a Controller.

Comment: This seems a little overkill... what is the general strategy for including simple javascript libraries into an angular project? What if someone isn't maintaining an angular port or you need a different version?

Answer (score 17):

There is a simpler and light weight solution. You can attach it to $window in a factory, so you can use it as angular dependency.

```
angular
    .module('moment-module', [])
    .factory('moment', function ($window) {
        return $window.moment;
    });
```

And use it as usual:

```
app.controller("ctrl", function($scope, moment) {
    $scope.date = new moment();
});
```

There is detailed explanation [here](http://www.jvandemo.com/how-to-properly-integrate-non-angularjs-libraries-in-your-angularjs-application/) about how to use external resources in angularjs.

Don't forget to add moment to your index.html