# Trouble injecting Moment, Asking for MomentProvider

Tags: momentjs

I have downloaded moment using Bower, and I have injected moment into the factory. However on load, I get the error:  Unknown provider: momentProvider <- moment.

I can not find any documentation about momentProvider.

Below is where I inject moment
`.factory('drbApproversFactory',[ 'moment', '$q', '$filter', '$log','$http', 'Constants',function(moment, $q, $filter, $log,$http, Constants){`

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23727411/4131048) a similar topic (I think that it's not a duplicate), maybe the answers can help you.